# React-Redux and Connect - Why is my state not updating on click?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and am writing a simple voting front end which allows the user to vote on their favourite framework (Angular, React, Vue). When a user clicks on a framework they would like to vote for, I intend to increment the votes in the store by one.

I'm using `combineReducers` and `connect` to facilitate this. However, after each click, the state is always one vote behind. After one vote the state is at 0. After 2 clicks, the vote state is at 1, etc.

Here is my `index.js` file wherein I create my store and render the app

```
//index.js
const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    "votes": votesReducer,
    "currentPercentages": currentPercentageReducer,
    "pastPercentages": pastPercentageReducer
});

let store = createStore(combinedReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is my action

```
export function voteAction(framework){
    return {
        type: "VOTE",
        payload: framework
    }
}
```

Below is the relevant reducer for updating the vote state

```
const initialVoteState = { angular: 0, react: 0, vue: 0 };

export function votesReducer(state=initialVoteState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "VOTE":
            if (action.payload === 'angular'){
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    angular: state.angular + 1
                });
            } else if (action.payload === 'react'){
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    react: state.react + 1
                });
            } else {
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    vue: state.vue + 1
                });
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Finally, here is the component I have which has the click handler to facilitate casting a vote and updating the state accordingly.

```
@connect(state => {
    return {
        votes: {
            angular: state.votes.angular,
            react: state.votes.react,
            vue: state.votes.vue
        },
        currentPercent: {
            angular: state.currentPercentages.angular,
            react: state.currentPercentages.react,
            vue: state.currentPercentages.vue
        },
        pastPercent: {
            angular: state.pastPercentages.angular,
            react: state.pastPercentages.react,
            vue: state.pastPercentages.vue
        }
    }
})
export default class InfoArea extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.votedAngular = this.votedAngular.bind(this);
        this.votedReact = this.votedReact.bind(this);
        this.votedVue = this.votedVue.bind(this);
    }

    votedAngular(){
        this.props.dispatch(voteAction('angular'));
        console.log(this.props.votes.angular);
        //the log above will output 0 after the first vote is cast, 1
        after the second vote is cast etc. Why is this the case? Should 
        it not be set to the correct value here since the action has 
        already been dispatched?

    }

    votedReact(){
        this.props.dispatch(voteAction('react'));
    }

    votedVue(){
        this.props.dispatch(voteAction('vue'));
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <div className="info-container">
            <img 
                style={{"marginTop":"25px"}} 
                className="app-img" 
                src={require("../../public/brainbulb.svg")}>
            </img>
            <h2 className="wide">What is your favourite front-end framework in 2017?</h2>
            <h4 style={{"marginTop": "0"}}>Click an image below to vote!</h4>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="images-container">
                    <img
                        onClick={this.votedAngular} 
                        className="framework-logo" 
                        src={require("../../public/angular.png")}>
                    </img>
                    <img 
                        onClick={this.votedReact}
                        className="framework-logo" 
                        src={require("../../public/react.png")}>
                    </img>
                    <img 
                        onClick={this.votedVue}
                        className="framework-logo"
                        src={require("../../public/vue.png")}
                    ></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also worth noting that when I cast a vote and view my store state in the browser console it is accurate. Yet, my component remains one vote behind. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not confident that console.log would be the best way to check the state/store. I think if you should look into the redux chrome extension so then you can see what's going on in redux more clearly. Your code seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not able to the the updated state immediately is because the operation of updating the store is async and writing

```
votedAngular(){
    this.props.dispatch(voteAction('angular'));
    console.log(this.props.votes.angular);
}
```

means that you are trying to check for the value as soon as the action is triggered. If you want to test the value, I would suggest you do it in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log(nextProps.votes.angular);
}
```

However, for such operations where you need to test for redux values, `redux-devtools-extension` is an ideal tool.

Comment: So every time you write to the store it is an async action? I'm not hitting any server to fetch data or anything I am just increasing a counter by 1. Why is this asynchronous?

Comment: The update to the store happens asynchronously, and before the updated data is available you console.log() is processed. Also updating a store can be an expensive operation and making it synchronous might leave the browser unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I have confirmed that the state is correct in componentWillReceiveProps.

If I want to do something like deploy "castVote" action then immediately after the store is updated deploy "updatePercentages" action should I be using a thunk to do this?